kivy apk android 11 and above write files to device
Iam trying download files from URL to Download directory in android after making another folder inside it
what happened is making folder with os.makedirs working well but saving files inside it or even inside Download directory not working unfortunately
I have tried the normal way
with open(output_file, "ab") as file:
    file.write()


it was working fine in android 10 with the right permissions but 11 and above not working any more
I searched a lot Until I came up with a library called the pyjnius, but unfortunately, because the documentation for it seems very unclear, it did not work for me
So is there any way to ensure that files are saved in shared storage in Android 11 and above?
although after many days of searching , tried some codes from chatgpt and not working
